# Azure CLI cannot add auto-scale conditions in azure function apps

Tags: azure, azure-function-app

I am trying to make a script to add custom auto-scale rules from azure CLI on more than 20 function apps but unable to find any parameter for the same.
My apps are all at Premium plan with separate App-service plans.
I am trying to add scale-out rules for each app.
Please share any link which does the same.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Azure Functions will auto-scale depending on various reasons, and the consumption plan will determine how much memory and CPU will be granted to each function app (source [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale)). There is a way to limit the amount of instances your function app will have, this will usually mean reducing costs.

The link below shows you what the Azure CLI command to use to update this value:

```
az resource update --resource-type Microsoft.Web/sites -g <resource_group> -n <function_app_name>/config/web --set properties.functionAppScaleLimit=<scale_limit>
```